# Is it bad etiquette to include Amazon affiliates tags in links?

Tags: discussion, links, etiquette, affiliate

#### Is it bad etiquette to include Amazon affiliates tags in links?

It doesn't seem unreasonable to me, but I will certainly not include them if the community frowns on the practice.

Answer (score 6):

At least on the main Stackoverflow site, Amazon links are automatically converted into the Amazon Affiliate links funding Stack Overflow. See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/), and [this post on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links).

Comment: Is that a yes or a no?

Comment: I presume it's more a case of "It's pointless" as I think the SO engine will munch your Amazon link and replace it with its own Amazon Affiliates link.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks, Edd :)