# Is it acceptable to undo edits removing affiliate links?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7547/8263) is full of affiliate links. They aren't disclosed by the individual who provided the answer. Further, I was amused to see it cited in the '[Are affiliate links allowed](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/661/8263)' question here on meta, where it is made clear they **are not allowed**.

Reading the comments, and especially its [revision history](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/7547/revisions), it is clear that the affiliate links have been removed by someone else, and then the affiliate links later restored by the original poster.

This has been going on for quite a while, and among established high-reputation users.

Is this acceptable here?

Comment: Another mod removed the referral links. I've added a comment requesting that the answerer not roll back the edits again as we are intentionally removing the referral part of the links. I'm not sure we should delete the post, but we should keep the referrals out of it.

Comment: @jrista The post is useful, please don't delete it. It was just so flagrant with the affiliate links that I posted it on meta instead of simply flagging it for a mod.

Comment: Lol wow. That is pretty blatant. Can the post or thread be locked? That is just bad. He should get a slap on the wrist for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. Those links should have stayed removed and the rollback reverted, or the post deleted.

Note that Amazon links are automatically converted to Stack Exchange referral links. Stack Exchange does a lot to promote community and sharing, but they *are* a for-profit company.